# cyrus imap does not start lmtp tcp socket, error message: Servname not supported for ai_socktype, disabling lmtp

Tags: services, tcp, socket, imap

**Problem**:

When starting cyrus imap with the following line in `/etc/cyrus.conf`:

```
SERVICES {
   ...
   lmtp     cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="[192.168.50.100]:lmtp" prefork=1 proto=tcp4 
}
```

to enable lmtp via tcp socket, the socket is not opened.
In the logfile the following message appears:

> Servname not supported for ai_socktype, disabling lmtp

Comment: I could not tag the question with the new tag cyrus or cyrus_imap due to low rep. Maybe someone else could add it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**:

> Servname not supported for ai_socktype, disabling lmtp

means that no entry for `lmtp` could be found in `/etc/services`.

Either add a line like:

```
lmtp      2003/tcp # Lightweight Mail Transport Protocol service
```

to `/etc/services` (and make sure the file is world-readable/mode 644)

or change the cyrus config file so that the port is given in the `listen` part instead of `lmtp`:

```
SERVICES {
   ...
   lmtp     cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="[192.168.50.100]:2003" prefork=1 proto=tcp4 
}
```

Reference: [cyrus service port numbers](https://www.cyrusimap.org/imap/reference/admin/ports/services.html)